# Displaying records side by side in one screen, in different modes

Tags: apex, visualforce, console

I want to display two opportunities side by side, so my users can compare them, and i can do that easily with `<apex:detail>` When they're both in view mode, it looks great. However, I want it to so that the users can edit them and still view the other. How do I do that? The only way I could think of it is overriting the edit button, sending the user to a "routing page", and then based on the URL sending the user back to the new screen similar to the bottom.however i'd lose any inline edits. That'll be a pain point.

I looked into the agent console, but it seems to limit you to mini page layouts, and my opportunities are massive.

https://cs15.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_agent_console_cheatsheet.pdf

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="false">
<style>
.tableStyle {border-collapse:collapse;}
.colStyle1 { width: 50%;text-align:left; padding-right:30px; border-right:1px solid #000;}
.colStyle2 { width: 50%; text-align:left; padding-left:30px; }

.rowstyle { padding:0px; }
</style>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" styleClass="tableStyle" width="100%" columnClasses="colStyle1,colStyle2" rowClasses="rowstyle">
<apex:detail inlineEdit="true" relatedList="false" />
<apex:detail inlineEdit="true"  relatedList="false"/>
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but how do you get two opportunities shown? I tried ?id=opp1&id=opp2 but it shows only two opp1 side by side

Comment: you're usinf the native id paramater. my params are called opp1 and opp2. try this, but replace my oppids with 2 of yours: compareOpps?opp2=006e00000049iQe&opp1=006e0000004QHvm

Comment: I tried but the page is blank - I do have changed the opp ids of course. It seems to me that the VF page doesn't contain opp1 or opp2 specified. I am a little confused.

Comment: For your problem, I guess one possible solution is to define a custom button to edit side by side which directs to a VF page which is similar to your current page. Instead of using <apex:detail>, you can use two custom component. I haven't tried though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you go without the console and instead just use a wrapper vf-page with two iframes which holds each one opportunity inside?

So you could control the behavior and avoid interferences in a simple way. If you use an other custom vf-page to view each of the two opportunities, you could even interact between iframe and top frame and adjust height dynamically to avoid scrollbars within scrollbars.

Comment: i can't get the iframes to work. there's an error with that... hang on and i'll post it...